# how to show help in pop up for the user to complete next step in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to see some image in pop up at certain locations of page. The pop up will appear with images at different location of page based on certain criteria passed by controller.

For example, when a user log in, i want to show a pop up with image A in the center of page. after he clicks anywhere, i need to show a different image in pop up somewhere on the right hand side of the screen. Also, I don't want to use java-script alert pop up. I have my own image that I want to show in pop up. I just want the image to appear in pop up.

I am not sure what technology to use for this. I am using Spring MVC, jsp.

Please direct.

Comment: The only way to have a popup in the same screen/window is with JavaScript... I'm not sure what you mean by "I don't want to use java-script pop up as they are full square"... You might want to edit that and provide more information as it seems to be an erroneous assumption on your part.

Comment: edited. please relook

Comment: You need to use JavaScript with a floating element (div or some other block element).  There a LOTS of pre-built, fully tested, and widely used JavaScript UI frameworks that would be of use, or you can write your own.  For pre-existing, I would check out jQuery w/ jQuery UI (has a "Dialog" already), Dojo, ExtJS, and many, many more.  I am sure that if you Google "JavaScript dialog" you would get lots of results.

Comment: Thanks. "JavaScript dialog"... this was the word I was looking for.